# Magento extension subfolder change

Tags: magento-1, php, configuration, routing

I am trying to localize an extension i bought from Magento store.

```
http://www.sitename.com/extname/ to http://www.sitename.com/myext
```

I have changed the config.xml file to do this change.

```
<routers>
        <extname>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Magestore_extname</module>
                <frontName>myext</frontName>
            </args>
        </extname>
</routers>
```

But the url doesn't change. Any thoughts? I am new to Magento.

Comment: Clear magento cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with the config.xml the first place I normally look is at the cache. There is a complete cache type called `Configuration` that stores the config and local xml files.

You can clear the cache in one of two ways.

1. Admin section `System->Configuration->Cache Management`
2. Remove files under `/var/cache`

I would suggest that if you are doing some development to disable cache at first as it can be a pain to have to keep clearing it. But I would always test with cache enabled afterwards to make sure that you get the desired results.

Comment: Exactly........